# Systems of products with unknowns in generalized arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

Consider a system of equations of the form $x y = z$ where the variables $x,y,z$ are taken from a common vector $\overline{t} = \overline{a} + \sum_{i = 1} \lambda_i \overline{b_i}$ where $\overline{a}, \overline{b_i} \in \mathbb{N}^k$ and $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is there an algorithmic way of checking whether the system has a solution?

Comment: Can you specify more clearly what is the input to the decision problem? e.g. are $a$, $\lambda_i$, etc. fixed?

Comment: I cleaned up my comments that are no longer relevant to the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is undecidable by a reduction from solvability of Diophantine equations (Hilbert’s 10th problem).

By introduction of new variables corresponding to subexpressions of a given polynomial, we can efficiently reduce the solvability of any integer polynomial system to solvability (over $\mathbb N$) of a system $S\cup P$, where $S$ consists of equations of the form $x_i+x_j=x_k$ or $x_i=1$, and $P$ of equations of the form $x_ix_j=x_k$. The solution set of $S$ is definable in Presburger arithmetic, and therefore [semilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_set), thus it can be (algorithmically) written as a finite union $S=\bigcup_jS_j$ where each $S_j$ has the form $\vec a+\sum_i\lambda_i\vec b_i$ as in the question. Then the original system is solvable iff for some $j$, $P$ has a solution in $S_j$.